# Can a reset level from a voltage supervisor be controlled for power-on transitions?

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, reset, power-on-initial

*This question is related to another circuit about I have talked in an previous post. But I think by the nature of the question, this must be treated apart, in a new post.*

I need to keep a signal from a 74ABT245 device at logic '0' during power on, while the system is starting. When an MCU on another board starts its firmware execution, it is putting the desired logic level in this pin. But it's too late.

The 74ABT245 output signal drives a D-type Flip-Flop (DFF) master reset (MR) input pin. While the 5 V rail is stabilizing and the firmware starts to change this value, the DFF outputs are activating. These outputs shouldn't be at high state (even high impedance could be right).

My priority is to find a solution for:

1. Forcing MR pin to GND only during power on process.
2. After power-on, the 74x245 device must be able to put HIGH or LOW level there.

The circuit is working properly after the power-on sequence because the MCU is sending a reset and the 74ABT245 is driving the MR pin LOW when it is desired.

I discarded a pull-down resistor solution because it's not working. The circuit has pull-up resistance that cannot be removed. So, voltage divisor appears on the pin (close to 4 V). During power-on it works fine as a pull down device. But after this moment, the reset is down when a VOH (logic HIGH) is on the 74ABT245 output.

So I remember a way to force LOW/HIGH reset levels during the starting, using voltage supervisors.

[image: typical supervisor circuit application]

But maybe there is a kind of circuit solution that could be added here on the red box:

[image: looking for a solution]

The questions:

- A supervisor device could be a great solution. But the bad news seems to be that this way doesn't allow any kind of change reset value control after the power stabilises. Is that right?
- Can anybody suggest me some ideas for doing this (red box drawing on DFF board scheme)? Even if there is no possible solution, it will be useful to know for me.
- If supervisor voltage is not a kind of solution, how would you control the power-on reset stability?

Comment: It should definitely be possible. But how, more details about schematic required. Do the boards share same 5V supply or not? Most voltage monitors have open-drain output so it might be very easy.

Comment: A one-shot pulse can be created by MCU or with a single gate with RC delay pulse width. But for reasons of clarity, show a timing diagram or logic table for DC OK, POR(reset), MCU output and RST input states with ,0,1 or x for each signal during Power On Reset

Comment: There are voltage supervisor chips out there that have a separate RESET input.  When asserted this input asserts the reset outputs of the voltage supervisor, which are also asserted when the voltages are coming up (normal supervisor function),

Comment: So your goal is to stop the 273FF chip from starting up until after the microcontroller sends a signal telling it to do so?

Comment: I find this question really hard to follow and understand, there's a gaps and leaps in it. Please can you edit your question and try to make it a lot tighter and clearer.

Comment: I think I understand what OP wants to do.  But it's really tricky, guaranteeing that it will work at the corner cases, especially if multiple supplies are involved.

Comment: @justme thanks, yes, thEy do it.

Comment: Please note that there is no such IC as a 245 or a 273. They are 74-series devices but You don't state the logic family so it could be, for example, 74LVC245. I have corrected this in your question (again) with a '74x' prefix, where 'x' can be LVC/ACT/HCT/etc., because 245 and 273 are ambiguous, not a good thing in engineering. Your question should be clear and, as far as possible, not needing interpretation. Also, quantities and units should be space separated and ICs output logic HIGH and LOW, not 1 and 0. Fixed now. (You overwrote these corrections so I've restored them.)

Comment: @LukeSackash yes it is. Thanks. Adding that: mcu does this by writing '0' into a 245 3state device input pin, then it was enabled and inputs pass to outputs. So one of this outputs goes to the 273FF reset pin.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 hi, thanks. I will try to put a diagram as soon as I can. I was watching them by osc but we did not save the images. So by the moment I can say that I have seen the reset activation about 240ms after turning on. I was thinking about RC delay solution adding a capacitor between pin and GND. As we have a fixed pull up 2K resistor I only need to increase RC by chosing greater capacitors. Knowing that this delay will be also present when normal operation too.

Comment: @SteveSh this sounds great. Could you put here some kind of references about this type of sepervisor? any little hint that helps me to find any example with this feature??

Comment: HINT Sort "PMIC Supervisors" by type RESET and sequence and smart and In-stock then choose

Comment: But you must define your sequence thresholds properly

Comment: @Suvi_Eu - For starters, just look on the TI web site.  I found a number of candidates with just  cursory search.  Use "voltage supervisor" for you search term.  Also get hold of TI's app note slyy167, "Voltage Supervisor
and Reset ICs: Tips, Tricks and Basics."  Probably has everything you need to know.

Comment: What is the purpose of the 245 buffer in this circuit?  Is there a reason you can't connect directly to the MCU?